# Release new version of android app

Tags: android, eclipse

I released new version of my application in eclipse with own signature and i increase version code.

When i want to install new version on device that installed old version on it,this message appears:

"an existing package with the same name with a conflicting signature is already installed."

Comment: It looks like you have a new signing key or at least not the same you used to create the apk that is currently installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason might be because you previously installed a debug version on your device which has a default key used by that debug version. 
  Releasing a new version with your signature doesn't match the debug key so you get that warning and should uninstall current version before installing the new one.

Comment: how to change debug version to release version in eclipse?

Comment: how to export app with own signature currectly?

Answer (score 0):

The key is

> ...of my application in eclipse with **own** signature...

if the signature is different than you used before, for any reason, you cannot install application with the same id (package name), unless you uninstall the old app first.